# Filtering realtime database data

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following firebase database. I would like to filter and list the orders which's deliveryDuration value is "45"

```
"orders" : [ null, {
    "comment" : "",
    "date" : "2018-07-09 10:07:18",
    "deliveryDuration" : "45",
    "delivery_address" : "",
    "item" : [ {
      "available" : true,
      "category" : "Dessert",
      "details" : "(Hausgemacht)",
      "name" : "Warmer Topfenstrudel",
      "price" : 3.9,
      "quantity" : 1
    } ],
    "orderVerified" : false,
    "telefon" : "",
    "userID" : "xyc@gmail.com",
    "userName" : ""
  }, {
    "comment" : "",
    "date" : "2018-07-10 10:07:33",
    "deliveryDuration" : "30",
    "delivery_address" : "",
    "item" : [ {
      "available" : true,
      "category" : "Dessert",
      "details" : "(Hausgemacht)",
      "name" : "Warmer Topfenstrudel",
      "price" : 3.9,
      "quantity" : 1
    } ],
    "orderVerified" : false,
    "telefon" : "",
    "userID" : "xyc@gmail.com",
    "userName" : ""
  }, {
    "comment" : "",
    "date" : "2018-07-10 10:13:13",
    "deliveryDuration" : "10",
    "delivery_address" : "",
    "item" : [ {
      "available" : true,
      "category" : "Spezialitäten",
      "details" : "Schweinschnitzel mit Parmesan gebacken auf Spaghetti Napoli",
      "name" : "Piccata Milanese",
      "price" : 12.9,
      "quantity" : 1
    } ],
    "orderVerified" : false,
    "telefon" : "",
    "userID" : "xyc@gmail.com",
    "userName" : ""
  }
}
```

I tried writing the following function:

```
getNewItems: function (order) {
       if (db.ref('orders').child(order).child('deliveryDuration').equalTo(45)){
       return db.ref('orders').child(order).child('deliveryDuration')
      }}
```

How could I get the filtered objects? I was thinking that that i write an if-else statement and the function returns the values what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
getNewItems: function (order) {
   return db.ref('orders').orderByChild('deliveryDuration').equalTo(45));
}}
```

This Firebase query takes each child node of the location you query, orders it by the `deliveryDuration` property, and then filters to only get the ones who are equal to `45`.

Comment: Would this bill for reading the entire orders tree or only the children where the deliveryDuration conditions == 45 is true?

Comment: If you have an index defined on the `orders` node for `deliveryDuration`, then it'll only charge for the nodes where that value is `45`. If you don't have an index defined, the client will read all data from the database (and log a warning about that), and you'll be charged for for all data read.

Comment: I did not know that, thanks for letting me know. One more small question, if my keys at /parentNode are incrementing numbers .e.g. { 0: {some data}, 1: {some data}, ... etc. } and i do startAt(0).endAt(10), will this always only charge for those 10 nodes rather than the entire /parentNode tree?

Comment: You get charged for the data that is downloaded. So as the example before: if the database returns only those 11 nodes, you only get charged for those. Btw: this should probably have been a new question, instead of a comment on one from a couple of year ago. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Sorry I will ask a question in future. Thanks for the help

Comment: Worked for after tweaking! many thanks ... new to firebase so i am learning